# Why returned OleDbConnection.GetSchema("Columns") has no rows while same code works for OracleConnection?

Tags: oracle, ado.net, oledb

I've made a utility method to get schema from a db table. In this case Oracle 11 db.

```
    public static DataTable GetColumnsSchemaTable(DbConnection cnctn, string tableName)
    {
        DataTable schemaTable;

        string[] restrictions = new string[3] { null, tableName, null };
        schemaTable = cnctn.GetSchema("Columns", restrictions);

        /* table name is case sensitive and in XXXX db table names are UPPER */
        if (schemaTable.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            restrictions = new string[3] { null, tableName.ToUpper(), null };
            schemaTable = cnctn.GetSchema("Columns", restrictions);
        }
        return schemaTable;
     }
```

This works fine when the cnctn is created with System.Data.OracleClient provider factory. When it's created with System.Data.OleDb provider factory the table has no rows. I have an other utility method to get connection strings:

```
    public static string GetDbConnectionString(DbConnection cnnctn, string provider, string server, string dbName, string user, string pwd)
    {
        if (cnnctn is OleDbConnection)
        {
            string usedProvider;
            if (provider == null)
                usedProvider = "msdaora";
            else
                usedProvider = provider;

            return string.Format("Provider={0};Data Source={1};User Id={2};Password={3};",
                    usedProvider, dbName, user, pwd);
        }
        else if (cnnctn is System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection)
        {
            return string.Format("Data Source={0};User Id={1};Password={2};",
                    dbName, user, pwd);
        }
        else if (cnnctn is Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection)
        {
            return string.Format("Data Source={0};User Id={1};Password={2};",
                    dbName, user, pwd);
        }
        else if (cnnctn is SqlConnection)
        {
            return string.Format("Data Source={0}; Initial Catalog={1}; User Id={2}; Password={3};",
                server, dbName, user, pwd);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

and the db connection works (i'm deleting rows before trying to get schema). All help will be appreciated.

Thanks & Best Regards - Matti

Comment: It seems that I have to give a schema somehow. Incidentally i got a table that has same name with some other table schema. I don't want to give all the tables a schema's name also in the code. OracleClient was happy with just table names. Any ideas how to do this? Maybe I gotta utilize the other schema collections also to fetch the schema but then I have to know the syntax for table name. Trying schema.table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I sorted it out. I made this code long time ago only for now deprecated OracleClient and left the possibility to use other connections / provider factories. I didn't remember anymore that the restrictions vary from connection to connection. So the correct usage is:

```
string[] restrictions = new string[4] { null, null, tableName, null };
```

for OleDbConnection.